# Scrollbar on safari renders over all overlays, popups and modals

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, scrollbar

I have a div with `overflow-y: scroll` on a page. The page also has a few popup modals and overlays. However, the scrollbar of the div renders above all of these overlays. I tried increasing the z-index over overlays but it won't work.
The scrollbar does not detect a hover in the region over the modals.

[Refer the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7FnN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same problem just now and an experimentally found out that if you set your modal `z-index` to more than **998** (999+) it will be higher than Safari scrollbar.

Not sure why this is happening, I guess this is just basic Safari mechanic, from now on I am setting `z-index: 1000` to my modals just in case.