# R Shiny DataTable - Scroll X Bar Invisible

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, scrollbar, dt

I'm developing a Shiny app and I often use datatable objects. I need a scroll bar in X axis to be able to see other columns in the app. I added a scroll bar to datatable by using datatable options.

However, it is too sticky. When you see the images, you will see the problem. If scroll bar remains sticky, it will be causing to appearon the modal dialog. Is it possible to make invisible scroll x bar? I have no idea about JavaScript by the way.

```
# Datatable Option
optlist <- list(
  autoWidth = TRUE,
  dom = 'rltip',
  #Scroll
  # deferRender = TRUE,
  # scroller = TRUE,
  scrollX = TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE,
  # Page Length
  pageLength = 25,
  # Search
  search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE)#,
)

# Render Datatable
output$bor_dt <- renderDataTable(server = T,{
  datatable(
    sblist()%>%
      rename_all(., list(~gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", .))),
    rownames = FALSE, # Remove rownames
    escape = FALSE, #Hyperlink
    class = "cell-border stripe display nowrap compact", # Borders
    selection = "single", # Satır seçimi
    filter = list(position = 'top', clear = TRUE, plain = F),
    # Options
    options = optlist
  )
})
```

[Datatable & Sticky scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1sSl.png)

[Sticky scroll bar & modal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eEvH.png)

Comment: Could you provide a full (and minimal) example, so that we can run it by copy-paste?

Answer (score 1):

As I can check similar issues for your problem. I saw that the scrollbars are provided by web-browsers in DataTables and most problematic browser is Safari as I seen. When I tried my pc, I think result is what you expect. So, can you replicate your problem with different browsers ? Then, we may understand this is safari related or general issue for all browsers.

[image: Result:]

For the modals part, I saw similar problems on SO and Github and there are several workaround solutions which you may use your app. Since I cannot replicate the modals part,can you add a dummy model to replicate your issue?

Similar Problems:

[How to prevent background scroll when bootstrap modal is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524718/how-to-prevent-background-scroll-when-bootstrap-modal-is-open)

[Issue with background scrollbar showing through modal in Safari only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237081/issue-with-background-scrollbar-showing-through-modal-in-safari-only)

[Scrollbar on safari renders over all overlays, popups and modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435351/scrollbar-on-safari-renders-over-all-overlays-popups-and-modals)

[Modal background scrollable (iOS Safari)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22311)